# SQL query to get most comments since last month

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables, one containing posts and other containing comments, There are millions of posts and 100's of millions of comments, the comments table also contains the post's ids. The comments are deactivated after some time, I want to know which posts had the most comments in last 30 days from before before being deactivated.

What I have to do is find max(comment_date) for each posts from comment table and count all the comments back 1 month from that date for each post.

so essentially I want to group by `post_id`, find `max(comment_date)` and get count of all comments from `max(comment_date) - 1 month` for each post. I am struggling to create the query to get this data?

The database is postgres 9.4.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On that amount of data, the query will take time.  One method is to use window functions:

```
select post_id, count(*)
from (select c.*, max(comment_date) over (partition by post_id) as maxcd
      from comments c
     ) c
where comment_date >= maxcd - interval '1 month'
group by post_id;
```

Comment: I don't understand the need of window function for this, Wouldn't `select c.post_id, max(comment_date) as maxcd from comments; group by post_id;` work the same in the sub query?

Comment: @rajat . . . You would have to join it back to the `comments` table to get the count you really want.  Using window functions should have better performance.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, I would appreciate it if you could have a look at my answer to this question. What do you think - is it possible to do two steps together? Is it possible to avoid explicit index seek for the `max date` and then for the `max date - 30 days`? I have a feeling that window function such as `FIRST_VALUE` could do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to use `LATERAL` join here. If you create an index on `comments` table on `(post_id, comment_date DESC)`, it may be more efficient than variant suggested by Gordon Linoff. It really depends on your data distribution. It may not be necessary to specify `DESC` in the index, optimizer may be smart enough to use it if it was `(post_id, comment_date ASC)`. But, the order of columns is important.

Here is [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/55899/4/0).

The query literally follows the steps you outlined in the question.

We scan `posts` table once. For each post we find the comment with the latest `comment_date` and subtract 30 days from it. This should be done by one seek of the index. Then we count all comments of this post after the found date minus 30 days. This should be done by the ranged index scan.

```
SELECT
  posts.id
  ,c_count.post_count
FROM
  posts
  INNER JOIN LATERAL
  (
    SELECT comments.comment_date - interval '30 days' AS max_date
    FROM comments
    WHERE comments.post_id = posts.id
    ORDER BY comments.comment_date DESC
    LIMIT 1
  ) AS c_max_date ON true
  INNER JOIN LATERAL
  (
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS post_count
    FROM comments
    WHERE
      comments.post_id = posts.id
      AND comments.comment_date >= c_max_date.max_date
  ) AS c_count ON true
;
```

It may be possible to do the two steps in one go (find max date, then count rows within 30 days interval) using window functions.